# MySql: How can i select a column by name if a subquery first selects it with min() or max()?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

```
select position from 
    (select prefix, min(position) 
    from Chart_Position 
    group by chartnum) as Foo;
```

gives:

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'position' in 'field list'

when `I select * from ...` The following columns are shown:

```
+----------+---------------+ 
| prefix   | min(position) |
+----------+---------------+ 
| 1964_232 |            87 | [rows truncated]
```

I'm trying to select the column titled above "min(position)" but I can't figure out how to reference it.  It seems like the min() is causing my trouble.

Thank you for taking a look!

**EDIT: FOUND IT!** I needed to alias the result of min(position) in the subquery.  Like so:

```
select position from 
    (select prefix, min(position) as position
    from Chart_Position 
    group by chartnum) as Foo;
```

Comment: If you can find the answer is less than a minute after posting the question, you aren't looking hard enough before posting the question.

Comment: Apologies.  I actually spent a while searching before posting, already had the question typed up--figured I'd post it in case someone else's searches hit it.  I'm new around here, still learning the ways...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You found it; you can use define an alias for an expression column in the derived table subquery, then you can reference them by that alias in the outer query.